# ERC20 Token: What is address(0)? And best practices for initial token distribution?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have a pretty boilerplate test token that I'm going to use to support a DApp project. Key functions I have questions regarding are as follows:

```
constructor() {
        name = "Test Token";
        symbol = "TTKN";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 1000000000000000000000000000000;
        //WITHOUT DECIMALS = 1,000,000,000,000; should be 1 trillion

        balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }

function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
    return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
}
```

First, a quick question about decimals and supply: did I set this up correctly to create 1 trillion of the TTKN token? And do I really need so many decimal places?

Second, what exactly is `address(0)`? My understanding of the constructor is that `address(0)` first transfers *all* the tokens to `msg.sender`, which is me, the person who deploys this contract.

And finally, what are the best practices for initially distributing the tokens? What I want is basically as follows:

a) Myself and a few other devs each get 1% of the initial supply

b) Our DApp, a separate smart contract, will get 50% of the initial supply, and will use this to reward users for interacting with our website/project

c) To accomplish a) and b), me, the contract deployer, should manually transfer these tokens as planned?

d) The rest of the coins... available to go on an exchange somehow (maybe out of scope of question)

So now that I've deployed this test token on remix and am getting a feel for how to transfer around the tokens, I want to understand the above points in relation to our project. Is my plan generally acceptable and feasible, and is it the case that as the initial owner I'm just making a bunch of `transfer` calls on the ETH mainnet eventually when I deploy?

Comment: address(0) - is the conversion of an integer 0 to the address type, null-address

Comment: What does it mean to `emit Transfer` from `address(0)`? Is that just some convention for how to send the initial supply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *did I set this up correctly to create 1 trillion of the TTKN token?*

This is one of the correct ways. More readable would be also:

```
_totalSupply = 1000000000000 * 1e18;
```

or

```
// 10 to the power of
_totalSupply = 1000000000000 * (10 ** decimals);
```

^^ mind that this snippet performs a storage read (of the `decimals` variable) so it's more expensive gas-wise

a well as

```
_totalSupply = 1000000000000 ether;
```

^^ using the [ether](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/units-and-global-variables.html#ether-units) unit, an alias for `* 1e18`

---

> *what exactly is address(0)*

If it's in the first param of the Transfer event, it means the tokens are minted. If it's in the second param, it means a burn of the tokens.

> *A token contract which creates new tokens SHOULD trigger a Transfer event with the `_from` address set to `0x0` when tokens are created.*

Source: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#transfer-1

---

> *initially distributing the tokens*

You can perform the distribution in the constructor. For the sake of simplicity, my example shows the "exchange" as a regular address managed by your team that will send the tokens to the exchange manually. But it's possible to list a token on a DEX automatically as well.

```
_totalSupply = 1000000000000 * 1e18;

address[3] memory devs = [address(0x123), address(0x456), address(0x789)];
address dapp = address(0xabc);
address exchange = address(0xdef);

// helper variable to calculate the remaining balance for the exchange
uint256 totalSupplyRemaining = _totalSupply;

// 1% for each of the devs
uint256 devBalance = _totalSupply / 100;
for (uint i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    balances[devs[i]] = devBalance;
    emit Transfer(address(0x0), devs[i], devBalance);
    totalSupplyRemaining -= devBalance;
}

// 50% for the DApp
uint256 dappBalance = _totalSupply / 2;
balances[dapp] = dappBalance;
emit Transfer(address(0x0), dapp, dappBalance);
totalSupplyRemaining -= dappBalance;

// the rest for the exchange
balances[exchange] = totalSupplyRemaining;
emit Transfer(address(0x0), exchange, totalSupplyRemaining);
```

Comment: This is an amazing answer and covers pretty everything I wanted to know. Kudos!